# Reference request for Statistical Learning Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, machine-learning

I want to learn about Statistical Learning Theory. I have a strong background in measure theory, probability theory and functional analysis. What would be a good resource/book to start learning Statistical Learning Theory in the most general setting?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following books can be very useful:

- Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David. Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms.
- Mehryar Mohri, Afshin Rostamizadeh and Amit Talwar. Foundations of Machine Learning
- Michael Kearns and Umesh Vazirani. An Introduction to Computational Learning Theory. MIT Press, 1994.

Also, you can find the following courses helpful:

1. [Understanding Machine Learning - Shai Ben-David](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPW2keNyw-usgvmR7FTQ3ZRjfLs5jT4BO)
2. [Computational Learning Theory by Varun Kanade](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/varun.kanade/teaching/CLT-MT2018/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Trevor, Tibshirani, Robert, Friedman, Jerome.  It covers a fair amount of material at a reasonable pace.  Also, it is quite rigorous when necessary and on top of that, it provides beautiful images to clarify the concepts.

Comment: I had a look at this book, but for my taste it had too little measure theory and functional analysis. I am rather looming for a really theoretical book rather than one giving and intuitive introduction. But I appreciate the siggestion, thanks:)

Comment: Ok, then I would recommend "All of Statistics" which is a bit more mathematical.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head (I'll add other sources later on)

- [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS_corrected_1.4.16.pdf)
- [Martin Wainwright's statistical learning theory course](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/stat241b/)
- [Sham Kakade's statistical learning theory course](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~skakade/courses/stat928/)
- [Peter Bartlett's statistical learning theory course](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2014spring-cs281bstat241b/)
- [Percy Liang's statistical learning theory lecture notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs229t/Lectures/percy-notes.pdf)

and references therein.